# Unicode / encoding with Wicket

Tags: encoding, utf-8, wicket

In Wicket, I am trying to include the text "frāctus m (feminine frācta, neuter frāctum)," in a webpage which is simply pulled from a static text file with the correct encoding (UTF-8, saved from Eclipse).  When rendered in the browser, it displays "frÄ�ctus m (feminine frÄ�cta, neuter frÄ�ctum)."  Is there a fix for how the rendering is encoded?  I added `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` to my main "template" page (from which the others inherit) but this didn't help.

Comment: The link in the accepted answer is about decoding POST requests which is not the problem you're having.

Can you post the code where you load the text file from disk?

Comment: That code is in Wicket.  By default, it just replaces ".class" with ".html" of the controller being called, loads that file as the view template, and lets the controller process it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to change all of the `ā` (Latin small letter a with macron) to `&#257;` and they should display properly, apparently Wicket is still determining [how to handle character encoding](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WICKET-3578).

**EDIT**

You might want to also take a look at http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/CharacterEncoding and ensure that the server is properly setup.

Comment: I knew about the HTML escape code; thanks for the link to the bug!  Cheers and have an upboat.

Comment: I edited my post to include more information about character encoding which might be of use.